# Trying to set an analyzer for my Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the following mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/borrador' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "item": {
       "dynamic": "strict",
       "properties" : {
            "title" : { "type" : "string" },
            "body" : { "type": "string"  },
            "source_id" : { "type": "integer"  },
}}}}'
```

I'm using the following [Elasticsearch-JDBC importer](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc) script to import all my data from my DB

```
#!/bin/sh

bin=/usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.1.1.2/bin
lib=/usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.1.1.2/lib
echo "Indexando base de datos..."
echo '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mydbip/mydbname",
        "user" : "username",
        "password" : "pw",
        "sql" : "select source_id, body, id as _id from table_name",
        "index" : "borrador",
        "type" : "item",
        "detect_json": false  
    }
}' | java \
       -cp "${lib}/*" \
       -Dlog4j.configurationFile=${bin}/log4j2.xml \
       org.xbib.tools.Runner \
       org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter
```

The thing is that I'm looking for an `analyzer` that fits my approach on a correct way but I'm a bit lost: **I'm looking for a way to use an `analyzer` that can adapt to multiple languages.**

This means that sometimes a entry of the DB is in spanish, english or any other languages. The user adds the data to the DB so it can be ANY language and the language itself it's not stored, this means I can't know which language has the current entry. Also,the languages are not mixed (there's no a row with two different languages).

Which is the best approach to archive this goal? It's better to use generic analyzer for all languages, or is better to build different analyzers for each language? If someone provides me a mapping with a `analyzer` would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use multi field for each language used `body.en`, `body.fr`, ...

For example :

```
"properties": {
                "body" : {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "fr": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "french"
                        },
                        "en": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "english"
                        },
                        "es": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "spanish"
                        },
                        "de": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "german"
                        },
                        "pt": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "portuguese"
                        },
                        "nl": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "dutch"
                        },
                        "dk": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "danish"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I already read this on the ES documentation but I didn't understand it correctly. With this, do I've to define the body language everytime I index an item (`body.en`, etc)? Or it's magic and with a generic `body` is enough?

Comment: It's magic ^^. When you index `body`, ES will analyze it for each multi field on it : `body.en` etc

Comment: This affects in performance if I'm not wrong. I mean, the string `hello world` for example is going to be analized by each and every language, right? This just happens when you index it, or when a search is done?

Comment: Yes, this will take more time to index, and use more resources